# Python - Pass an operator using literal string?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dictionary of columns names (keys) and their data types (values). The datatypes are literal strings and I'm trying to convert the columns in my PySpark df to the defined data types i.e.

```
for k, v in dict.items():
   df.withColumn(f'{k}', col(f'{k}').cast(v))
```

Obviously the above doesn't work because `'ByteType()'` doesn't exactly equal `ByteType()`. Does anyone have any creative workaround to this?

Comment: "The datatypes are literal strings" Why? Where did the dictionary come from?

Comment: They came from another dataframe

Comment: And that Dataframe? Did you read it from a file? Is it manually created? Or do you mean that you created it *by checking the column names and types* of a Dataframe? Is the goal to make another Dataframe with the same specifications? Or just what? Please read [mre] and make it possible for others to see the problem exactly as you experience it.

Comment: I read it in from a data source. Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: I would just suck it up and make a dictionary from strings to data types if it's necessary for the data types to be read as strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import * # don't forget to import
# Solution 1
for k,v in dict.items():
   # returns a new Spark DataFrame so you have to declare new df as df
   df = df.withColumn(f'{k}', col(f'{k}').cast(v)) 
df.printSchema() # check dataframe's schema
```

Solution 2. I don't know your column's datatype but you can convert ByteType() to FloatType() if your column's value range is not between -128 and 127.

Answer (score 0):

After reading comments, it seems that you simply want to cast datatypes from one dataframe to another.

You can do it like this:

```
df2.select(*[F.col(c).cast(t) for c, t in df1.dtypes])
```

Full example:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('1', '2')], ['c1', 'c2'])
print(df1.dtypes)
# [('c1', 'string'), ('c2', 'string')]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2)], ['c1', 'c2'])
print(df2.dtypes)
# [('c1', 'bigint'), ('c2', 'bigint')]

df2 = df2.select(*[F.col(c).cast(t) for c, t in df1.dtypes])
print(df2.dtypes)
# [('c1', 'string'), ('c2', 'string')]
```